# Get Absolute url using hook_preprocess_node

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, uri

We are attempting to change the `$variables['url']` from a relative to absolute URL within the `mymodule_preprocess_node()` hook. The `$variables['url']` is displayed as a `<a>` element within our `node--page.html.twig` template.

**How can we set the `$variable['url']` so that it uses the `absolute` URL?**

`node--page.html.twig`

```
<a href="{{ url }}">
  {{ label }}
  {{ content.field_text }} {# custom text field #}
</a>
```

What we tried within `mymodule_preprocess_node()`.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url; 

function mymodule_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $options = [
    'absolute' => true,
  ];
  $variables['url'] = URL::fromUri($variables['url'], $options);
}
```

This results in the following error message:

> The URI '' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri() (line 281 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Url.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get this to work, I did the following. This assume you have access to the `$node` object, which you would if you are performing this within the `hook_preprocess_node()` hook.

```
$variables['url'] = $node->toUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString();
```